# React Native: Why are some modules in package.json but not in node_modules?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, package.json

In my React Native project, there are a bunch of dependencies in my `package.json` file that aren't in my `node_modues` folder. Specifically, none of the `@react-native-community/...` modules are there. Is this normal?

Answer (score 0):

All the dependencies in package.json are stored in the node_modules directory.

and as you are asking for @react-native-community dependencies are also in the node_modules but not separately, all the node_modules of the react-native-community are stored in the directory @react-native-community in the node_modules.

You can check out it by node_moduels/@react-native-community/<<SUB_PACKAGES>>